# Access denied error when creating S3 bucket versioning for a bucket using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Given AWS policy below, the user/role I am using can do everything with S3 at the moment but, for some reason `s3/PutBucketVersioning` is failing. Same user assumes role in all accounts for cross-account access first then creates resources or modifies them. MFA is not activated for this user. Is there anything you can think of?

I read post below but nothing obvious so far.

- [Why am I getting a "403 Access Denied" error when I try to modify a bucket policy in Amazon S3?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy)

**AWS Policy**

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

**Bucket**

```js
provider "aws" {
  profile = "production"
  alias   = "production"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account" {
  provider = aws.production

  bucket        = "company-team-team-production"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "team_team_group_bucket_access_rule_in_production_account" {
  provider = aws.production

  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account.id
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account.id

  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

**Terraform logs**

```bash
aws_s3_bucket_versioning.version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account: Creating...
[INFO]  Starting apply for aws_s3_bucket_versioning.version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account
aws_s3_bucket_versioning.version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account: applying the planned Create change
[DEBUG] Waiting for state to become: [success]
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request s3/PutBucketVersioning Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
PUT /?versioning= HTTP/1.1
Host: company-team-team-production.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.2.6 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/dev (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go/1.44.91 (go1.18.4; darwin; amd64)
Content-Length: 123
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=MYSECRETKEYID/20230415/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-md5;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=59.....d8d2dba2
Content-Md5: ...w==
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: 59.....d8d2dba2
X-Amz-Date: 20230415T135250Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip
provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.30.0_x5:
<VersioningConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Status>Enabled</Status></VersioningConfiguration>
-----------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/PutBucketVersioning Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Sat, 15 Apr 2023 13:52:50 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Id-2: 59.....d8d2dba2=
X-Amz-Request-Id: 3456789dfghj
provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.30.0_x5:
provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.30.0_x5:
-----------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>1234567yhjfg</RequestId><HostId>u+h=</HostId></Error>
[DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response s3/PutBucketVersioning failed, attempt 0/25, error AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 1234567wert, host id: 59.....d8d2dba2=
[ERROR] Response contains error diagnostic: diagnostic_detail= diagnostic_severity=ERROR diagnostic_summary="error creating S3 bucket versioning for company-team-team-production: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 1234567wert, host id: 59.....d8d2dba2=" tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.0/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 @module=sdk.proto tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_req_id=.....d9nnn tf_resource_type=aws_s3_bucket_versioning tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange timestamp=2023-04-15T14:52:50.537+0100
vertex "aws_s3_bucket_versioning.version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account" error: error creating S3 bucket versioning for company-team-team-production: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 1234567wert, host id: 59.....d8d2dba2=
╷
│ Error: error creating S3 bucket versioning for company-team-team-production: AccessDenied: Access Denied
│   status code: 403, request id: 1234567wert, host id: 59.....d8d2dba2=
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_versioning.version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account,
│   on s3_bucket_versioning.tf line 6, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account":
│    6: resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "version_team_team_group_bucket_in_production_account" {
│
provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.30.0/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.30.0_x5 pid=65069
provider: plugin exited
```

```bash
$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.2.6
on darwin_amd64

$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.0 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Comment: Try looking in Cloudtrail to make sure the request is coming as you expect.